Permanently disable Asus service on Windows
I want to permanently disable the Asus Optimization service on Windows 11, but after disabling this service, it automatically starts after some time (same thing happens with the Windows Update service as well).
How do I prevent the service from starting automatically?  

Change Automatic into Desactivated in the properties, right-clic on service you want to change.

Why don’t you just uninstall the software? ASUS software is never required for the system to run.

Yes, I tried all that but it happens again.
